# Why do c# textbox.AppendText() newlines disappear when using \n as line terminator?

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

I am using a multiline textbox, and I am getting behavior I cannot fully explain. I use

```
 textbox.AppendText("line \n");
```

to append a new line to a textbox. When using this 3 times, I get

```
line 
line 
line
```

displayed in the textbox. Now, I resize the textbox. The text becomes

```
line line line
```

That is, the newlines disappear. I know I should be using

```
 textbox.AppendText("line "+ Environment.Newline);
```

So I know how to **solve** the problem. I would like to know why, when using "\n", the newlines initially appear, but disappear when resizing.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as explained below. System.NewLine "works" on Windows, eg, because the `\r` sticks around after the `\n` gets removed. I'm seeing that with UWP and Win10 now... I assign `"\r\nhenever"` to a textbox's SelectedText, and the `SelectedText` value immediately show `"\r> henever"`, for example. Where does the `\n` go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On resizing, that "\n" character gets removed, as resizing also controls the new line creation and deletion based on "\n", System.Env.NewLine never gets omit.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a line that looks like this:

```
textbox.AppendText("line \n");
```

you should use this line instead:

```
textbox.AppendText("line "+ Environment.NewLine);
```

This occurs because the newline for unix is `\n`, but for non-unix (i.e. Windows) it is `\r\n`. When the box is resized, the system newline is replaced, thus if you have only `\n`, it will be lost in the resize.

Reference:
[MSDN: Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)